# How to integrate a Continous Integration with Microsoft Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, continuous-integration, azure-virtual-machine, appveyor

I'm developing a Node.js App but I deploy this app in a Azure Virtual Machine (Ubuntu) manually. I want to deploy it from specific GitHub branch (Master) into Virtual Machine, can I use Appveyor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Appveyor CI** which is available on the Azure Marketplace which is published by Appveyor.

Link: [Appveyor CI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/appveyorci/appveyor-ci/)

[image: Appveyor CI]